# R-Markdown: Problems with kableExtra (loadNamespace)

Tags: r, r-markdown, kableextra

I wanted to create a pdf document using RMarkdown and kable:

````
---
title: "markdown testfile"
author: "author"
date: "2023-05-01"
output:
  pdf_document: default
  html_document: default
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
options(repos = list(CRAN="http://cran.rstudio.com/"))
install.packages("tidyverse")
install.packages("kableExtra")

library(tidyverse)
library(kableExtra)
```

```{r}
iris %>% 
  dplyr::slice_sample(n = 10) %>% 
  kbl() %>% 
  kable_styling()
```
````

The error message I get is:

```
Fehler: Laden von Paket oder Namensraum für 'kableExtra': fehlgeschlagen
.onLoad in loadNamespace() für 'kableExtra' fehlgeschlagen, Details:
Aufruf: !is.null(rmarkdown::metadata$output) && rmarkdown::metadata$output %in%
Fehler: 'length = 2' in coercion to 'logical(1)'
Ausführung angehalten.
```

Translated to English:

```
Error: Failed to load package or namespace for 'kableExtra':
.onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'kableExtra', Details:
Call: !is.null(rmarkdown::metadata$output) && rmarkdown::metadata$output %in%
Error: 'length = 2' in coercion to 'logical(1)'
Execution halted.
```

I've already tried re-installing the kableExtra-package.
If I click on the execute button of the code chunk it executes without any errors. However, the output looks strange:

[image]

Comment: What is your version of the `rnarkdown` package?  I have `packageVersion("rmarkdown")` return 2.21; your version may be older.  The 'logical of length two' is something R itself got more strict about recently, it could be you are missing a package update.  In general I strongly recommend running `update.packages()` regularly.

Comment: Make sure you installed the latest version of R (which is 4.3.0 at the time of writing this comment). Then, change the repository and set the dependencies=T option and retry using the following code: `install.packages('kableExtra', dependencies = T, repos = 'https://CRAN.R-project.org/')`.

Comment: Unfortunately re-installing `kableExtra` did not solve the problem. I'm currently using Version `1.3.4` and my R-Version is `4.3.0`. So everything should be pretty up to date.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've encountered the same error in an RMarkdown file using `kableExtra` after updating to R Version 4.3.0. For me, listing solely one output format in the header solved the problem.

In your case, dropping `html_document: default` from the RMarkdown header should eliminate the error. The header in your example should read:

```
---
title: "markdown testfile"
author: "author"
date: "2023-05-01"
output:
  pdf_document: default
---
```

Alternatively, you could install a patched version of `kableExtra` that solves the problem:

```
devtools::install_github("kupietz/kableExtra")
```

The error arises when evaluating [lines 23-28](https://github.com/haozhu233/kableExtra/blob/292f607159/R/zzz.R#L23-L28) in kableExtra's `.onLoad` hook in a markdown file with more than one output. Since R Version 3.4.0 "Calling `&&` or `||` with LHS or [..] RHS of length greater than one is now always an error" (see [R changelog](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/NEWS.html)). There is already a related [GitHub issue](https://github.com/haozhu233/kableExtra/issues/750) and a [possible solution](https://github.com/kupietz/kableExtra/commit/5cd02b3afd) by kupietz.

Comment: Thanks, thats great! Is there also an issue already for the tables not being displayed correctly any more?